# Android banner not working

Tags: android, smartbanner

When I run it it gives a java heap space error and again it give message "your project contain errors please fix them before running" and again message display related  to "an internal error occured please close workbench". I also use the test id of mobile but same error occurs each time.

Layout file:

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`enter code here`
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize=" SMART_BANNER "
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7222219345251053/8664557124" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

newadmobtutorialmanifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.androidbegin.newadmobtutorial"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="9"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

mainActivity.java

```
    package com.androidbegin.newadmobtutorial;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private InterstitialAd interstitial;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from activity_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
            // Insert the Ad Unit ID
            interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7222219345251053/8664557124");

            //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

            // Request for Ads
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

            // Add a test device to show Test Ads
            // .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            // .addTestDevice("EB81B984CF6F807FED26757A39F8FF")
                    .build();

            // Load ads into Banner Ads
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

            // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
            interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // Call displayInterstitial() function
                    displayInterstitial();
                }
            });
        }
        public void displayInterstitial() {
            // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs “c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe”
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=2028m
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-Xms2028m
-Xmx6120m
```

Comment: Whilst I assume that you want someone to explain why you're getting a java heap space error it would be much better if you actually asked this question, and also mentioned what you have tried to do to fix it (other than posting to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set adUnitId from dynamicly, e.g.

```
<uradreference>.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7409237681170791/6275305467");
```

also try with `ads:adSize="BANNER"` first! It should work.

Comment: when i checked  the libraries (android private library is google-play-services.jar) and (android dependencies in google-play-services_lib.jar)in build path>>configure build path>>order and export  then it goes hang and when i unchecked that than  it give error"'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.BannerXmlActivity.onCreate"

Comment: i already used everything which is present on stack flow related to this error "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.BannerXmlActivity.onCreate". but still error exist.